# Natural deduction has me stuck

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have been trying to break down these two formula correctly using natural deduction, and now I am stuck and confused. Below there is my attempt to derive the propositional logic consequences. I need your help. Listing form is also acceptable. Thanks already. 
\begin{align}
(1.) &\lnot p \to (p \land r) \vDash \lnot p \to r\\ 
(2.) &\vDash (p \to (q \to (p \to (p \lor q))))
\end{align}

*Unsure Breakdown of what I did in question (1). Question (2) is hard for me:*
I derived $\lnot p \to r$ with V-E, since  $\lnot p$ is $\lnot p$, and $r$ can be derived from $p \land r$.

[image: Q 1]

Comment: Do you know the rule $\to_\text{intro}$ for introduction of the implication in natural deduction? Do you know how to assume something and how to discharge it?

Comment: @Taro. No, i don't. I just started leaning Logic few weeks ago. Please help me if you can.

Comment: Which inference rule do you have to prove a formula of the form $A \to B$?

Comment: @Taro. I am not sure as it wasn't given. Just the formula, then solve for the proportional logical consequences.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a rule named  “→-I” or something of that sort?  The first exercise is asking you to prove $\lnot p\to r$, and if you don't have a rule for proving things of the form $A\to B$, there is no way to do that.

Comment: @Taro. Then it is, the elimination- and introduction rules of the
natural deduction system. It has to do with assumtion, premises, and...

Comment: Do you have a reference or a link to the list of the inference rules you are allowed to use? Or can you add this list to your OP? Natural deduction can be presented  in many different ways, so I would like to know which formalism you are using before I write an answer. If I choose the wrong formalism you don't understand anything and I waisted my time. Moreover, in this list you must have a rule called $\to_I$ or similar, as  @MJD told you before, and it is important to understand that rule to solve both exercises.

Comment: @Taro & MJD. This must be it. Argumentation analogous to the rule " → - I " is sometimes
known as hypothetical argument and structure of the rule of  "→ - E" . Just got that from the textbook.

Comment: This was an assumption made to solve a very similar question "Intuitively, we should be able to derive p ∨ r with V -E, since p is p and r can be derived from q ^ r. If p is true, then p ∨ r is true and if a ^ r is true,then r is true and also p ∨ r".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is not clear which kind of formalism you use for natural deduction, I use the one I prefer, the tree-like one.

The idea of the proof is that, given the hypothesis $\lnot p \to (p \land r)$, if you *suppose* $\lnot p$ then you can conclude $r$, because by *modus ponens* (the rule $\to_E$) from the hypothesis $\lnot p \to (p \land r)$ and the further assumption $\lnot p$ you get $p \land r$ and in particular $p$ (by $\land_E$). So, if you *discharge* the further assumption $\lnot p$ (using the rule $\to_I$), you get a proof of $\lnot p \to r$ under the hypothesis $\lnot p \to (p \land r)$.

Formally, a derivation in natural deduction with hypothesis $\lnot p \to (p \land r)$ and conclusion $\lnot p \to r$ is the following:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\lnot p \to (p \land r) \qquad [\lnot p]^*}{\dfrac{\dfrac{p \land r}{r}\land_E}{\lnot p \to r} \to_I^*}\to_E 
\end{align}

Note that, since in the hypotheses and conclusion there are no occurrences of the connective $\lor$ (disjunciton), you need not use inference rules $\lor_E$ or $\lor_I$ here.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I accept your solution, and i am very sorry for the stress. As i said i am new to the subject. Can you attempt Question 2?

Comment: @Harrisson - I guess Question 2 is another question, you can ask it on another post. And while asking for a solution, show what you have tried yourself and where you get stuck. If you understand well my answer here, you should be able to solve Question 2 by yourself. The general idea is the same, just the formulas change.

Comment: With your solution, do i have to calculate further and do cancellations/deduction, or it ends here?

Comment: @Harrisson - What I wrote in my answer is a derivation in natural deduction from the hypothesis $\lnot p \to (p \land r)$ to the conclusion $\lnot p \to r$. In other words, it is a derivation in natural deduction showing that $\lnot p \to (p \land r) \models \lnot p \to r$.

Comment: Hello Taro. I just revisited this satisfactory solution and was wondering, what if at the start ¬p→(p∧r) was to be P v (p∧r)? Would the assumption still be valid if i just replace it in the formal derivation formula, or will it change everything?

Comment: @Harrisson - No, if you started from the assumption $p \lor (p \land r)$, the derivation would be completely different. In particular, on the top of the derivation you couldn't use the rule $\to_E$, you would use the rule $\lor_E$, which has a completely different shape.

Answer (score 1):

(Posted after the previous answer was accepted.)

Readers may find this presentation easier to follow. It uses another form of natural deduction to get the same result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for your contribution.